# C# Limit left decimal places

Tags: c#

How do you limit the number of places on the left hand side of a decimal?

So 123.45 needs to be 23.45.

I would like the output to be a decimal.

Comment: You want to print it out? `value.ToString("#0.00")` or something like that, but if you want to limit the *data*, thats a different question...

Comment: Limit what exactly? User input? String representations? Upper bound of an input? What have you tried/researched?

Comment: (252.30m).ToString("##.##") gives me 252.30

Comment: (252.30m).ToString("00.00") gives me 252.30

Comment: That gives me a string I can convert back to a decimal, ideally I want a decimal though.  Either way I don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `modulo` and `ToString(string Format)`, so

```
var resultString = (number % 100).ToString("#00.00");
```

is the correct operation

Comment: Needs to be flexible for the size on the left.  I want strictly 2 places, regardless of size.  E.g. 12345 also needs to be limited to 45.

Comment: If the OP wants this as a `decimal` then really all they need is `var result = number % 100;`.

Comment: @Savage: well, modulo 100 is exactly what you want. Rest is about formatting.

Comment: Here's a solution where the number of places is variable `var result = number % (int)Math.Pow(10,numberOfPlaces);`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need "one hundred twenty-three" to become "twenty-three," one arithmetic way to do that is "mod(100.0)."  Works equally well for positive or negative numbers.

Another approach might be to convert the value to a string, then lop-off some of the leading digits/characters.  (This would avoid applying yet-another arithmetic operation to a floating-point value, risking the dreaded "off by one-cent" that gets accountants and other types *so* upset.)  Requires more debugging on your part, though.